# Dark background instead of custom one - but only on ICS

Tags: android, background, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have a problem with my app on ICS (Google Nexus is testing device).

My app uses a fully custom appearance. My layouts have own background drawables buttons have their own drawables etc. So I do not use the default style anywhere. Also I did not define a style anywhere.

My problem is now: The app looks fine on any device I tested on that is pre-ics (e.g. 3.1, 2.3 etc). On ics however the background drawable is overridden with the dark gray background (Holo.Dark/Light ???).

My custom background is quite bright and the text is black. On ICS the background is dark gray and the text still black (since I defined it as black). So the text is unreadable.

What I want is: On any device **including ICS** I want the app to display my custom background. I do not want to use any default theme.

I hope this question has not been asked before. I believe somebody else must have had the same problem but I could not find anything on Google or SO...

**EDIT:**
Ok here is the layout that fails. Since it quite long I left out irrelevant parts and added some comments. Also before anyones asks. The background drawable is available for any device. Also important to know is that this layout is used for all activities as basis. All activities inflate their own layouts into the content-FrameLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <!-- the background of this LL is _not_ shown on ICS -->

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_menu_top"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <!-- the background of this LL is shown on ICS -->

    <!-- the title of the activity at the top of the screen -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/main_frame_title"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <!-- some other views here -->
    </LinearLayout>


    <!-- this text is not visible on a dark background but on a bright one -->
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/main_frame_subtitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:text="Subtitle"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

    <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_frame_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
    <!-- every activity inserts its specific layout here -->
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_frame_breadcrumb"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_menu_top"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <!-- breadcrumb bar at the bottom -->
    <!-- many ImageButtons are here  -->
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I'm not prepared to answer your question, but I expect people will answer you more readily if you include the offending layout.

Answer (score 0):

I was actually having a similar issue with the background image of a layout not displaying on my Galaxy Nexus. Turns out at some point I had enabled 2D hardware graphics acceleration:

Settings > Developer Options > Force GPU rendering

Disabling this feature fixed the problem, and now my background images are displaying just fine. It was very frustrating troubleshooting the issue, but after finding the answer I saw that this particular option breaks a pretty wide range of different graphics issues. Anyway, hopefully that's it in your case. Hope this helps.

Comment: Since I use a lot of animation I do not want to turn off hardware rendering. :(